# VBA ByRef argument type mismatch when using function in subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I have a MatMul function for multiplying 2 matrices and returning the resulting Array. Gomb2_Click is triggered via a button and for each trigger it applies the transformation described by the matrix to the initial point p0.

(Both the matrix and the initial p0 point are hardcoded) \

**In the Gomb2_Click subroutine the p1 = MatMul(mat, p0) line gives me a ByRef argument type mismatch error and I don't know why.**

Thanks!

```
Function MatMul(a As Range, b As Range) As Range
    If a.Columns.Count <> b.Rows.Count Then
        MatMul = 0
    End If
    ReDim res(a.Rows.Count, b.Columns.Count)
    For i = 1 To a.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To b.Columns.Count
            tmp = 0
            For k = 1 To a.Columns.Count
                tmp = tmp + a(i, k) * b(k, j)
            Next k
            res(i - 1, j - 1) = tmp
        Next j
    Next i
    MatMul = res
End Function


Dim colnum As Integer
Set colnum = 0
Dim p0 As Range
Set p0 = Range("B6:B7")
Dim mat As Range
Set mat = Range("B2:C3")

Sub Gomb2_Click()
    Dim p1 as Variant
    Set p1 = MatMul(mat, p0)
    Range(Cells(6, 3 + colnum), Cells(7, 3 + colnum)).Value = p1
    colnum = colnum + 1
    p0.Value = p1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have code floating outside sub/functions?

Comment: `Set colnum = 0` is problematic too. `Set` should be removed.

Comment: You really need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and then you need to declare all your variables.

Comment: The variables I put outside are meant to be global, Isn't this the way I can do that? I just don't want them to be reinitialized every time I call the subroutine

Comment: It's customary to put public /global variables at the top of the module

Comment: ...but you can't have an assignment outside of a sub/function.

Comment: I put everything inside the subroutine, got rid of the "Set colnum = 0", still gives the same error

Comment: You would need `SET MatMul = res` if it is returning a range but res is an array so signature is wrong.  `Function MatMul(a As Range, b As Range) As Variant` for example.